# Extruder get loose

Tags: pla, hotend, anet-a6

**Printer:** Anet A6

I'm gaving some trouble with a loose hot end. I was trying to peel of some PLA when I noticed the whole thing was kinda loose. I could pull it out very easy.
[image: Loose hot end]

So I tried to put it back, but it's verry loose and I don't know what exactly is wrong.
[image: Put it back in]

I'm not sure if I broke something, or doing something wrong. Does anyone know how to fix this or do I need a new extruder or hot-end?

Kind regards.

## Update:

As Trish said in the accepted answer, the heatbreak is broken. When I've opened the extruder it became more clear:

[image]
[image]

I'm happy cause this is a fix for about 10 euro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am sorry to inform you, but your picture looks like your hotend has a broken heatbreak. The heatbreak is the screw that connects the heater block with he coldend.

Your first picture clearly shows that the tp 2 or 3 windings of the screw are ripped off. Probably from tightening the nut against the codend carriage and this way applying tremendous force - the lower picture hints that it was tightened far too strong.

You are lucky however, as replacement heatbreaks are easy to come by and cheap.

Comment: Yup this is the problem, thanks! I will update my post with some image that make it more clear.